# TestNG Silently kill ExecutorService

Tags: testng

I am trying to write a test which uses `ScheduledExecutorService` to send request to the mocked downstream service in testng but the test return immediately without actually wait for the `ScheduledExecutorService` to run any background job.

```
      @Test
    public void test() {
        int theadNum = 32;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(theadNum);
        Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Thead: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Does anyone know why? I guess it's because TestNG does not honor the background thread and only honor the main one but no luck with the search. Any doc or know issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

generally java method won't wait for thread to stop. Try awaitTermination for the main java to wait for all the thread to complete.

scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Eg: `scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

for more information check [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))